# How to plot the graph using hist() function of matplotlib for "binned data"

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, binning

I  am  new in matplotlib. I have data  binned data.

```
         Level              Quantity
0      (199.533, 271.74]  (10.213, 39.4]
1      (199.533, 271.74]  (10.213, 39.4]
2      (54.903, 127.327]  (10.213, 39.4]
3     (127.327, 199.533]  (10.213, 39.4]
4     (127.327, 199.533]  (10.213, 39.4]
...                  ...             ...
5105   (54.903, 127.327]  (10.213, 39.4]
5106   (54.903, 127.327]    (39.4, 68.5]
5107   (54.903, 127.327]  (10.213, 39.4]
5108  (127.327, 199.533]  (10.213, 39.4]
5109   (54.903, 127.327]  (10.213, 39.4]
```

I want to make 2 histogram graph named "Level" and "Quantity" of each bin of "Equal width".
I have tried this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample binned data for the two variables (Level and Quantity)
data = {
    'Level': ['(199.533, 271.74]', '(199.533, 271.74]', '(54.903, 127.327]', '(127.327, 199.533]', '(127.327, 199.533]'],......
    'Quantity': ['(10.213, 39.4]', '(10.213, 39.4]', '(10.213, 39.4]', '(10.213, 39.4]', '(10.213, 39.4]'],......
}

df_binned = pd.DataFrame(data)


plt.hist([df_binned['Level'], df_binned['Quantity']], bins=10, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7, label=df_binned.columns)
plt.legend()
plt.title('Stacked Histograms of Binned Variables')
plt.xlabel('Bins')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

It is not reading the bins  in `plt.hist()` function

> df_binned['Level']

> df_binned['Quantity']

How i cann plot binned data?
How to prepare  the  data  for  making histogram graph?

Comment: First of all, you plot binned data using `bar`, not `hist`.

Comment: Histogram work on raw data points, not binned data.

Comment: You are right "Histogram work on raw data points, not binned data" .Now the question is how should we **prepare**  binned data for histogram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need data preparation

```
df_binned = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_binned['Level']   = df_binned['Level'].dtype(str)
df_binned['Quantity']=df_binned['Quantity'].dtype(str)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).